# Asyntack values are coming,but fragment show blank page.when i return back from third fragment the content are showing

Tags: android

I used viewpager in activity..in that i called three fragment..I used service for each fargment.but the content for firsy fragment is not coming..when i come from third fragment the first fragment value are coming

My code:
Activity page:

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.abservetech.adstar.Model.SellingItem;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ABSERVETECH on 11-Jul-16.
 */
public class Invitation extends AppCompatActivity {
    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";
    private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
    private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    String price,image,name;
    List<SellingItem> itemList = new ArrayList<SellingItem>();
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invitation);
        final Intent i=getIntent();
        price=i.getStringExtra("price");
        image=i.getStringExtra("image");
        name=i.getStringExtra("name");
        System.out.println("val11--"+price+name+image);
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.invitation);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();

        View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_titletext_layout, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                Gravity.CENTER);
        TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_textview);
        textviewTitle.setText("trackstra");


        abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#313B6f"), Color.parseColor("#313B6f"));
    }

    private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Selling(), "Selling");
        adapter.addFrag(new Buying(), "Buying");
        adapter.addFrag(new Watching(), "Watching");



        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            Boolean first = true;
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0){
                    onPageSelected(0);
                    first = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.println("pageee" + position);
               }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println("pageeeitem" + position);
            /*switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Selling();
                case 1:enter code here
                    return new Buying();
                case 2:
                    return new Watching();

            }

            return null;*/

            return mFragmentList.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

        }


    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.folder, menu);
        if(name!=null){
            MenuItem Folder = menu.findItem(R.id.Folder);
            Folder.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            MenuItem Folder = menu.findItem(R.id.Folder);
            Folder.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.Folder) {


           Intent i=new Intent(Invitation.this,Archive.class);
            i.putExtra("image",image);
            i.putExtra("price",price);
            i.putExtra("name",name);
            System.out.println("invv---"+price+name+image);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

My fragement page:
other two fragment page is also same like this fragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.example.abservetech.adstar.Model.ItemObject;
import com.example.abservetech.adstar.Model.SellingItem;
import com.example.abservetech.adstar.Model.page1;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Selling extends Fragment {
    // Store instance variables
    private String title;
    private int page;
    private GridLayoutManager lLayout;
    RecyclerView rView;
    List<SellingItem> itemList = new ArrayList<SellingItem>();
    RecyclerViewAdapter sellAdapter;
    private PrefManager prefManager;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    String url;

    // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
    public static Selling newInstance(int page, String title) {
        Selling fragmentFirst = new Selling();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", page);
        args.putString("someTitle", title);
        fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pd=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prefManager = new PrefManager(getActivity());

        new sellinglist().execute(prefManager.getuserid());
    }


    // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
       // View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);


        System.out.println("sell--"+prefManager.getuserid());
        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

        RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(itemList);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public  class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<SellingItem> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<SellingItem> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<SellingItem> itemList) {
            this.itemList = itemList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_list_watching, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, final int position) {
        holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
        //holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
        System.out.println("imggg1111"+itemList.get(position).getimage1()+itemList.get(position).getName());
        final SellingItem m = itemList.get(position);
        if (m.getimage1() != null) {
            if (!m.getimage1().equals("null")) {
                try {

                    url = String.valueOf(new URL(m.getimage1()));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("llllll"+m.getimage1());


                Glide.with(Selling.this).load(String.valueOf(url)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true).into(holder.countryPhoto);
            }
        }
        holder.countryPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Marksold.class);
                //add data to the Intent object
                intent.putExtra("image", itemList.get(position).getimage1());
                intent.putExtra("price",itemList.get(position).getprice());
                intent.putExtra("name",itemList.get(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("desc",itemList.get(position).getdescription());
                intent.putExtra("catid",itemList.get(position).getcatid());
                intent.putExtra("id",itemList.get(position).getid());
                intent.putExtra("proid",itemList.get(position).getproductid());
                System.out.println("intent---"+itemList.get(position).getcatid()+"******"+itemList.get(position).getprice()+"-----"+itemList.get(position).getimage1()+"..."+itemList.get(position).getdescription());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }
}

    public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView countryName;
        public ImageView countryPhoto;

        public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    class sellinglist extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd.setMessage("loading");
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "http://abservetechdemo.com/projects/android/olx/public/mobile/user/selling";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);


            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",prefManager.getuserid() ));
                //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_id", ""));
                // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_ownerid", ""));
                // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", ""));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.d("url", "mainToPost==" + url);
                Log.d("mainToPost", "Selling---" + nameValuePairs.toString());


                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamToStringExample str = new InputStreamToStringExample();
                String responseServer = str.getStringFromInputStream(inputStream);
                Log.d("response", "response -----" + responseServer);
                JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(responseServer);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("product");

                for (int i1 = 0; i1 <jsonArray.length(); i1++) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i1);

                        SellingItem movie = new SellingItem();
                        movie.setid(jsonObject.getString("user_id").toString());
                        movie.setproductid(jsonObject.getString("id").toString());
                        movie.setName(jsonObject.getString("name").toString());
                        movie.setimage1(jsonObject.getString("image").toString());
                        movie.setprice(jsonObject.getString("price").toString());
                        movie.setdescription(jsonObject.getString("desc").toString());
                        movie.setcatid(jsonObject.getString("cat_id").toString());




                        String image = jsonObject.getString("image").toString();
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
                        String price2 = jsonObject.getString("price").toString();

                        System.out.println("sellingimggg"+name+price2+image);
                        System.out.println("sellingimggg1"+" "+image);


                        movie.setimage1(image);
                        movie.setName(name);


                       /* name = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
                        productid = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();
                        prefManager.setproductid(productid);
                        name2 = jsonObject.getString("name").toString();
                        price2 = jsonObject.getString("price").toString();
                        desc2 = jsonObject.getString("desc").toString();
                        address2 = jsonObject.getString("address").toString();
                        String lat2 = jsonObject.getString("lat").toString();
                        String lng2= jsonObject.getString("lng").toString();
                        String created2 = jsonObject.getString("created").toString();
                        String distance= jsonObject.getString("distance").toString();*/
                        //System.out.println("titleeeee"+image+" "+productid+" .."+name2+price2+desc2+address2);

                        /*Glide.with(getActivity()).load(String.valueOf(url)).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                                .skipMemoryCache(true).into(holder.countryPhoto);*/
                        itemList.add(movie);


                        try{
                            GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                            rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
                            rView.setAdapter(sellAdapter);

                        }catch (Exception e){

                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            try{

            }catch (Exception e){

            }


            pd.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my title is wrong....Its Fragment issue

Comment: if your title is wrong you should edit it instead of commenting it

Comment: Yeah..if you have any solution,plz update it